# Midje autotest not reloading files in Emacs Cider on Windows

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider, midje

I'm currently working through the Midje tutorial:
https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/A-tutorial-introduction

I load the repl using `cider-jack-in` and can successfully run `(autotest)` which runs the tests.

However, when I change either the source or test files (and save them), the repl doesn't trigger a reload of the files and re-run the tests.

The reload works fine if I run the REPL from the command line.

I'm running Cider 0.8.1 nREPL 0.2.6 Clojure 1.4.0 on Windows 7.

Has anyone else had a problem with getting the REPL in Cider to work correctly with autotest and get it to rerun the tests when the source/test files are changed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by updating the midje and lein-midje versions:

.lein/profiles.clj

```
   {
  :user {:plugins [[lein-midje "3.2"]]}
  :repl {:plugins [
    [refactor-nrepl "2.0.0"]
    [cider/cider-nrepl "0.10.2"]
  ]}
}
```

project.clj:

```
(defproject cjtest "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]]
  :profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[midje "1.6.3"]]}})
```